# Add new membership types to an existing membership profile

Tags: civimember, profile

I have a profile containing membership fields, and when I created the profile I added a number of membership types. In the profiles administration page, the profile type says:
Membership::DPN UK - Dru: DPN UK - Full: DPN UK - Student: DPN Aus - Full: DPN Aus - Student

Now, I have expanded the number of membership types this profile could be used for, so I want to add more membership types to this list. The profile is currently unavailable to people with these new membership types.

How do I do this? Apologies if I'm missing something completely obvious.

I'm in Civi 5.35.2 and Drupal 7.80

Comment: "when I created the profile I added a number of membership types" doesn't quite make sense. You add the membership types to the Custom Fields, not to the Profiles.

Comment: I am sorry Andyg8, I do not fully understand your question.  Are you trying to have custom fields for the membership? Those can be controlled per-membership type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the confusion here folks, I was mixing 'profiles' with 'custom field sets'.

My membership profile contained custom membership fields and this profile wasn't available when editing or creating some specific membership types.

However, what I didn't realise was that when setting up custom membership fields you must choose which memberships you want these fields to apply to.

I should have gone to Civimenu > Administer > Customise Data and Screens > Custom fields > [my custom field set] > Used for: memberships[choose the correct membership types].

Once I'd chosen the correct membership types, my custom fields became available to these memberships when I edit or create them.

Whew. That's hard to describe in words, yet obvious in just a couple of screens. Hope it all makes sense and helps the next person who makes this mix up.